# Comparing dates: "comparison of Date with nil failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date

I have a Client model which has many projects. In the project model I want to validate that the project start date is always before or on the same day as the project end date. This is my project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :end_on, :start_on, :title

  validates_presence_of :client_id, :end_on, :start_on, :title
  validate :start_has_to_be_before_end

  belongs_to :clients

  def start_has_to_be_before_end
    if start_on > end_on
        errors[:start_on] << " must not be after end date."
        errors[:end_on] << " must not be before start date."
    end
  end
end
```

My application works as expected and gives me the specified errors in case the validation fails.

However, in my unit test for the projects, I am trying to cover this scenario, deliberately setting the start date after the end date:

```
test "project must have a start date thats either on the same day or before the end date" do
    project = Project.new(client_id: 1, start_on: "2012-01-02", end_on: "2012-01-01", title: "Project title")
    assert !project.save, "Project could be saved although its start date was after its end date"
    assert !project.errors[:start_on].empty?
    assert !project.errors[:end_on].empty?
end
```

Strangely, running this test gives me three errors, all referring to this line `if start_on > end_on` in my validation method, saying `undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass` twice and `comparison of Date with nil failed` once.

What can I do to make the tests pass?

Comment: Fix - don't have `nil > x`. It won't work.

Comment: @pst But why is start_on nil?

Comment: So, now we're getting somewhere! Where is it setup such that `start_on` (as specified as a named argument) will update the `start_on` accessor? And what happens if it's set as a string and not a real time object? What if it's set after the constructor? That is, follow the trail. The fluff reported is not the fluff you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a Project that has string values for :start_on and :end_on.  That's unlikely to work.  Rails might try to be smart and parse those, I'm not sure.. I wouldn't count on it.  Odds are some coercion is going on and the values are getting set to nil.

I would do this:

```
project = Project.new(client_id: 1, 
                      start_on: 2.days.from_now.to_date, 
                      end_on: Time.now.to_date, 
                      title: "Project title")
```

Comment: Perfect, that fixed the test, thank you! Also, I changed my project model to using the [date_validator gem](http://blog.codegram.com/2011/2/date-validation-with-rails-3), so now the code is much cleaner: `validates :end_on, date: { after_or_equal_to: :start_on }` and `validates :start_on, date: { before_or_equal_to: :end_on }`